# Matrix of linear layout and manipulation in code

Tags: android, android-gui

Let say that I have an layout in res/values named layout1.xml.

In this layout I have only one linear layout (the black one on the picture)

The thing I want to do is to add an array of linear layouts just like on the picture.
The red ones are linearlayout with horizontal orientation that contains 5 other linear layouts.
I want to do everything in code and I want to set an onclick listener to each of the layouts so when one is clicked I want to hide it. Everything needs to be putted in a function that will return a Layout and the this method should take prams for the rows and cols

```
public LinearLayout getLayout(int rows,int cols){
       return the_layout;
}
```

[image]

Comment: And where did you encountered problems?

Answer (score 0):

You make a LinearLayout with the constructor new LinearLayout(context)

You add layouts with parentLayout.addView(childLayout).

You should be able to do the rest.